# How to rotate a photo in 3d like this (CSS3 - HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d, css-transforms

When a user enters a photo like (A) .. I need it to be transformed to be like (B) .. Using a Placeholder image like (C) or just using rotation or something.
I tried CSS3 rotateX, rotateY and perspective but it looked creepy

[Sample Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brQVo.jpg)

Comment: You should add rotateZ

Comment: @BegmuhammetKakabayev But I think rotateZ will just rotate it in its plane (2d rotation) .. while it looks 3d in the image